# defining function in MOTD (Ubuntu)

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Is it possible to define a function in the MOTD on a Ubuntu box?

I have the following in my motd.tail file:

```
#!/bin/sh
? () { echo "$*" | bc -l; }
echo
date
echo
```

However the function definition doesn't work if I login to the box, i.e.:

```
? 10*2
?: command not found
```

Any ideas on how I can define the function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most distros have a system-wide bashrc file that is suited for things like this.

On Debian, this file is: /etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: Putting the definition in bash.bashrc did work. Thank you, however can you explain to me why it doesn't work in motd.tail? For my own benefit....cheers

Comment: motd.tail isn't sourced, it's just appended to motd:

On Debian, there's a /etc/init.d/bootlogs script that cats motd.tail and appends it to the motd file:


     **[ -f /etc/motd.tail ] && cat /etc/motd.tail >> /var/run/motd**